# How to get Pixel Aspect Ratio(PAR) from WMV clip in DShow Graph?

Tags: video, directshow, aspect-ratio, wmv

By the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) for Pixel Aspect Ratio:

```
DAR = SAR x PAR 
(Display Aspect Ratio, Storage Aspect Ratio, Pixel Aspect Ratio)
```

I have a wmv video with 2048x1080(256:135) resolution. Window Media Player (WMP) can extract the **PAR**, `15:16`, so that `WMP` can render this clip as `16:9(= 256:135 * 15:16)`.

Currently I can only get **dwPictAspectRatioX**/**dwPictAspectRatioY** from [VIDEOINFOHEADER2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd407326(v=vs.85).aspx) as 256/135. This value looks like a **SAR** by the resolution or the **DAR** ignore the **PAR**.

How can I get the `PAR` information from `DShow` graph?

p.s 
I'm using `[ASF Reader]-[DMO]-[VMR7]` as filter components in Graph.

PotPlayer cannot read the PAR either, so that it renders this clip with aspect ratio `256:135` instead of `16:9`.

Updated,

I found out that
[ASF_Reader_Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd390984(v=vs.85).aspx)::[IWMHeaderInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd798504(v=vs.85).aspx)::[GetAttributeByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd798519(v=vs.85).aspx)::[Atrributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd743066(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is a attribute [AspectRatio X](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd743057(v=vs.85).aspx) ([Y](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd743058(v=vs.85).aspx)) with the following meaning:

> The AspectRatioX attribute contains the width component of the
>   **pixel aspect ratio** for a video stream.

I am trying to queryInterface or queryService via IServiceProvider from ASF reader filter, but it always return **E_NOINTERFACE**.

Still need more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

`VIDEOINFOHEADER2::dwPictAspectRatio` gets you ratio, which is adjustment for non-square pixels in the encoded image. That is, if you enforce `dwPictAspectRatio` when you present video and you assume that monitor itself has square pixels, you get proper physical aspect ratio.

> By contrast, a 720 × 576 D-1 PAL image has a SAR of 720/576 = 5:4, but is displayed on a 4:3 display (DAR = 4:3).

- `biWidth`, `biHeight`, `rcSource` have pixel dimension values (720x576) - **SAR**
- `dwPictAspectRatio` instructs to show 4:3 - **DAR**